# cart session array

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I am building a simple shop cart and I am getting the following array from product page(when the user submits add to cart button)...

```
Array ( [product_id] => 1 [weight] => 2 [size] => 4 [type] => cafe [cost] => 6323.86 )
```

and after that I am saving it to `session` to showing later on cart...

```
$_SESSION['cart']= $data; //$_POST values into $data
```

it works great for if user adds only 1 product into cart, but if he adds another product the $_SESSION['cart'] array replaces with new value, but i want it save all selected product's details, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put another data level into your cart:

```
$pid = $data['product_id'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$pid] = $data;
```

which would do the simple task of recording that this item's been put in the cart. You'd need to add extra logic for handling quantity updates and whatnot.

However, of major note: if that 'cost' field is being roundtripped through the client, DO NOT TRUST THE VALUE. it will be extraordinarily simple for someone to add massive quantities of expensive items and set the price to 0. Boom goes your ecommerce system.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, how can i get all the stored value after adding `$pid` to array as i am currently using  `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value)` , please suggest thanks.

Comment: i liked yours suggestion about eCommerce system btw, thanks for that, please help me with my above question.

Comment: with that foreach, your `$value` would be the same the `$data` you put into the cart, so `$value['type']` would be 'cafe'.

Comment: thanks, can you even help me with getting sum of stored cost in array? how can i get total_cost from above array?

Comment: loop over the cart and sum up `$value['cost']`

Comment: can you please example code or suggest me something to read, that would help me lots, thanks.

Comment: sorry, but that's bedrock basic php... if you can't handle that sort of fundamental thing, then (no offense intended) you shouldn't be building an ecommerce system in the language.

Comment: got it worked, i have created a function for this. thanks for yours help.